# Where I can find quantum entanglement, real experimental raw data

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement

For analysis purpose, I am looking for raw data from real entanglement experiment with spin measured at two detectors, at various combinations of angles, but preferably at a single combination of angles.

To be precise, I am looking for individual pair detail data captured in the sequence it was measured as described below. The data can be for photons, but preferably for electrons.

Pair#----angle of detector1----spin  outcome1----angle of detector2----spin outcome2

1---------30---------------------UP----------------120--------------------DOWN

2---------30---------------------UP----------------120--------------------DOWN

3---------30---------------------DOWN-----------120--------------------UP

and so on .. This is the example of information I need, format can be different as long as sequence is preserved. Angles 30/120 are also just for example, they can be any angles.

If someone could please point me to such data. It is fine with me even if it is very large amount of data, I will handle it for analysis purpose.

If there are multiple sources of data, more the merrier. It will be also helpful to have location/distance information about generation and measuring devices

Comment: Usually measurements of entanglement is not done in this way. What is done instead is called quantum state tomography. The idea is to accumulate coincidence counts of various combinations of basis states on the two sides and then use this data to reconstruct the quantum state. One can then compute the concurrence of the state as a measure of the entanglement. Is there a reason why you would want the data in this particular form?

Comment: @flippiefanus: Well, unless we have sequential data, how can we analyse it for patterns. I want to do pattern analysis on the data to verify if the measurements are really independent of the preceding measurements. I think unless disproved, there is a reason to think the past measurements influence subsequent pairs so that the statistical correlation is shaped. For details on what I mean, please read "More scrutiny of statistical correlation" on Page 3 here (http://vixra.org/pdf/1607.0453v1.pdf) - .

Comment: What do you expect to learn from a sequence of random values? Why do you expect an optical entanglement experiment to produce less random sequences than an ordinary light source?

Comment: @CuriousOne: What I want to analyze is whether the entangled pairs are independent of previously measured pairs, or they somehow are influenced by previous measurements in order to shape up the statistical correlation. I have given detailed  example in  "More scrutiny of statistical correlation" on Page 3 at http://vixra.org/pdf/1607.0453v1.pdf

Comment: I see. Well in that case the data would also depend on the type of quantum system. Many experiments work with photons that are produced in a parametric down conversion process. For such a case the subsequent measurements of photons would not be affected by previous measurements.

Comment: @flippiefanus: I tried reading "parametric down conversion process", could not figure why it would be any different in context of shaping up statistical correlation.

Comment: You can ask the same question about any light source without entanglement. Such correlations have been observed on starlight, by the way, which surprised some people, even though they, too, are perfectly explained by the quantum mechanics of light with finite bandwidth.

Comment: What kind of correlation was observed with starlight, the same that we observe with entangled pairs? I am only talking about the statistical correlation among entangled pairs. Arn't particles of entangled pairs supposed to part opposite ways and so, are we sure we are getting both sides of entanglement from star light? Quantum mechanics does explain the correlation, no doubt on that, that is proved experimentally. I want to analyze the cause/pattern of correlation.

Comment: One can ask the question, why would two consecutive measurements have any statistical correlations? From a physics perspective, it would imply that the first measurement somehow affects the state that would be observed in a subsequent measurement. In a system where we measure consecutive photons produced by a process such as parametric down conversion there does not exist a mechanism for the first measurement to affect the production of subsequent states. Hence, we do not expect to see such correlations.

Comment: Consecutive events can have "independent" statistical correlation just like the coin example, or it can have a "balancing" statistical correlation just like you keep pouring dirt at one place and it takes shape of a heap.  There may not exist the influence, But I only want to analyze the sequential data and prove/disprove it. What if something comes out of data that does indicate an influence? That is why I think, unless this analysis has already been done, it is an important analysis to be done.

Comment: OK, granted. In that case, since nobody probably thought they would see anything interesting, nobody would have bothered saving such raw data in a repository. So you may need to hook up with a group with this type of experimental capability and convince them that this may be an interesting experiment to do.

Comment: Incidentally, such (non-obvious) correlations would also say something about the nature of the entanglement. For a maximally entangled state the outcome of a measurement should be completely unbiased and therefore completely uncorrelated with previous measurements.

Comment: @flippiefanus: With so much hype around entanglement in the pop science, it would be a shame if nobody bothered to scrutinize the data to the deepest level, and throw away the raw data, or even worse, not even record it in sequence. Do you have any information about such groups that have these capabilities?

Comment: My best guess is to contact a group doing polarization entanglement using type II parametric down conversion. Go to the arXiv; search for polarization entanglement and see which groups are working in that field. There should be many.